# The background color is not rendering correctly on an animation I am trying to create on with the package react-moves

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the react package react-moves to create an animation of three separate stripes that will appear on a page when the page refreshes. The background color doesn't seem to be rendering correctly. My react component is entered below;

```
class Stripes extends Component {

state = {
    stripes: [
        {
            background:'#98c5e9',
            left: 120,
            rotate: 25,
            top: -260 ,
            delay: 0
        },
        {
            background:'#ffffff',
            left: 360,
            rotate: 25,
            top: -397,
            delay: 500
        },
        {
            background:'#98c5e9',
            left: 600,
            rotate: 25,
            top: -498,
            delay: 1000
        }
    ]
}

AnimatedStripesHander = () => (
    this.state.stripes.map((stripe, index) => (
        <Animate
            key={index}
            show={true}

            start={{
                background: '#ffffff',
                opacity: 0,
                left: 0,
                rotate: 0,
                top: 0
            }}

            enter={{
                background: [stripe.background],
                opacity: [1],
                left: [stripe.left],
                rotate: [stripe.rotate],
                top: [stripe.top],
                timing: { delay: stripe.delay, duration: 500, ease: easePolyOut },
                events: {
                    end() {
                        console.log(stripe.background)
                    }
                }
            }}

        >
        {({opacity,left,rotate,top,background})=>{
                return(
                    <div
                        style={{
                            background,
                            opacity,
                            transform: `rotate(${rotate}deg) translate(${left}px,${top}px)`
                        }}
                    ></div>
                );
            }}
        </Animate>
    ))
)
```

The issue I am having trouble with is the background tag in the style object returned at the bottom. This background is erroring but I just can't seem to understand why. When I remove it everything else in the animation works very good however not the background color, has anybody got any experience with react-moves?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no npm package `react-moves` so I'm assuming that you're using `react-move`.

The [docs](https://github.com/react-tools/react-move#cadillac-interpolation----depends-on-d3-interpolate) for `react-move` say that you need to use a third-party package to use color interpolation:

https://github.com/react-tools/react-move#cadillac-interpolation----depends-on-d3-interpolate

Comment: I do have this package installed but I don't think what I'm trying to achieve is an interpolation. From reading the docs what I can gather is; In the start function of the animate component the state of the component is initialized, then the state is updated in the enter function. But for a reason I haven't been able to figure out the background updates to 'NaN' rather than the hex code I have referenced in my state.